# LQG: Why does gravity attract (not repel)?

Tags: gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

I read that LQG can (with the spinfoam formalism) give the Einstein equation when $h$ tends to zero.
See the metrics created by an object in the sky. The equations of the geodesics contain a parameter (the mass) with positive sign. Another sign would make planets repel. Is there also in LQG a same parameter that discard repelling?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605922/2451

Answer (score 4):

Asking this is like asking how the Standard Model explains why friction is exothermic. There’s a complex chain of approximations involved in both cases.

LQG (at least it’s spinfoam formulation) reduces to General Relativity in the classical limit. General Relativity reduces to Newton’s gravity in the non-relativistic weak field approximation. Newton’s gravity is an attractive force.

Comment: Where can I find a derivation of general relativity from spin foams?

Comment: @MitchellPorter Rovelli explains it in a lot of detail in his “Covariant LQG” textbook

Comment: Does it boil down to equation 8.109 in http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~rovelli/IntroductionLQG.pdf ? ... Is there actually an argument somewhere, that these configurations dominate the path integral?

Comment: @MitchellPorter your link doesn’t open for me unfortunately. The whole chapter 8 (called “classical limit”) is dedicated to this computation, it is an extensive computation that uses the stationary phase approximation to evaluate approximately the LQG spinfoam amplitude. The end result gives you the Regge action, which is equal to the Einstein-Hilbert action evaluated for a 4-simplex space time (this is because we chose to evaluate the amplitude on a 4-simplex space time to make the calculation simpler). The same calculation can be done for more complex space times.

Comment: @MitchellPorter ah I opened the link finally. Yeah, that's the mathematical form of the claim "GR is the classical limit of spinfoam LQG". There is actually an argument (actually, better – a computation) that this formula is correct. A special case for the 4-simplex space-time is described earlier in chapter 8 (see sections 8.1, 8.2, 8.3), then there are some words about generalizing this to arbitrary space-times (Muxin Han has obtained a lot of impressive results there essentially confirming 8.109 numerically, I'm not sure whether it was also derived analytically, but I'm sure it is possible)

Comment: So if one wished to carry out this argument in the context of e.g. two masses attracting each other (i.e. the OP's question) - do you have any suggestions of how to do it? Chapter 9 talks about coupling a fermion field to gravity, would that be the way? Or is there something simpler?

Comment: @MitchellPorter yeah, LQG is pure gravity, so you’d have to couple it to matter first. But the attractive nature of the force can be seen already after establishing the classical limit. Interestingly, in the deep quantum regime LQG seems to also repel... Recent works on LQG black holes show that singularities don’t exist because of this new repelling force

Comment: @MitchellPorter oh another method that comes to mind — one can try to compute the approximate s-matrix of gravitons on flat space time (this has actually been done for spinfoam LQG by Rovelli et al, sorry, I’m on the phone and it isn’t convenient to search for it now, please Google for the paper if interested). From the form of that s-matrix one can infer that semiclassically, gravity is an attractive force. No need to couple matter.